# Error running android app from shoutem v5

Tags: shoutem

I'm getting the following error after I do a shoutem `run-android`

> Starting: Intent { cmp=com.shoutemapp/.MainActivity } Error type 3
>   Error: Activity class {com.shoutemapp/com.shoutemapp.MainActivity}
>   does not exist. Starting: Intent {
>   cmp=hr.apps.n4476/com.shoutemapp.MainActivity }

What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is connected with this [React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5546) issue. Even though you get an error, your app still runs successfully, am I right? Your app is successfully installed onto the device (or simulator). If it doesn't open up automatically, open it manually. It should work.